# Firefox with CKEditor shortcuts: get event in CKEDITOR window

Tags: jquery, plugins, command, ckeditor, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to prevent the FF default action via CKEDITOR customized shortcuts.

I've tried following code

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('pluginName', {
 init: function(b) {
   b.addCommand('cmdName', { /*shortcut CTRL + SHIFT + C*/
     exec: function(b) {
        // functionality 
        b.window.$.event.stopPropagation();
     }
   });
 }
});
```

In chrome b.window.$.event gives "keybordEvent". In FF b.window.$.event is undefined.

How can i get the current event in FF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/jske66kf/). Also take a look on [`CKEDITOR.commandDefinition#exec`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.commandDefinition-method-exec) and [`CKEDITOR.editor#setKeystroke`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-setKeystroke). Use <kbd>CTRL(CMD)</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to test the behaviour.

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
    plugins: 'toolbar,wysiwygarea,basicstyles',
    on: {
        pluginsLoaded: function() {
            this.addCommand( 'customCommand', {
                exec: function( editor ) {
                    console.log( 'Executing', this.name );

                    // Uncomment this to allow default keystroke action.
                    // return false;
                }
            } );

            this.setKeystroke( 
                CKEDITOR.CTRL + CKEDITOR.SHIFT + 67, 
                'customCommand' 
            );
        }
    }
} );
```

I hope it explains the problem. As long as `exec` returns anything but `false`, a default keystroke (quite likely a devtools panel, i.e. Firebug) will not be executed.